# jupyter notebook %%time doesn't measure cpu time of %%sh commands?

Tags: shell, jupyter-notebook

When I run python code in a jupyter-lab (v3.4.3) ipython notebook (v8.4.0) and use the `%%time` cell magic, both cpu time and wall time are reported.

```py
%%time
for i in range(10000000):
    a = i*i
```

```
CPU times: user 758 ms, sys: 121 µs, total: 758 ms
Wall time: 757 ms
```

But when the same computation is performed using the `%%sh` magic to run a shell script, the cpu time results are nonsense.

```bash
%%time
%%sh
python -c "for i in range(10000000): a = i*i"
```

```
CPU times: user 6.14 ms, sys: 12.5 ms, total: 18.6 ms
Wall time: 920 ms
```

The [docs for %time](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-time) do say "Time execution of a Python statement or expression.", but this still surprised me because I had assumed that the shell script will run in a python subprocess and thus can also be measured. So, what's going on here? Is this a bug, or just a known caveat of using `%%sh`?

I know I can use the shell builtin `time` or `/usr/bin/time` to get similar output, but this is a bit cumbersome for multiple lines of shell---is there a better workaround?